# Trying to put a wrap around a photo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image stay centered in the main box and still get wrapped inside the border, this being auto since there are several pictures and they differ in size.

this is the css:

```
.bild2  {
border:3px solid #999;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-opera-border-radius:8px;
-khtml-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:20px;
box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 0px 24px;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
margin: auto;
```

}

and html:

```
<div class="bild2" style="width:406px;">
  <a href="../index.html">
    <img src="images/boyP.jpg" onclick="var node=parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode; if( node.click ) { return node.click(); } else { return true; }">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you getting now?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend placing the image as a `background-image` and setting the `background-position` to `center center`.

Comment: do you mean in the html? i am a beginner :). I am using more pics and want to use the same css.

Comment: Post the related html and css so that I can show you how to do it.

Comment: html:

<div class="bild2" style="width:406px;"> 
      
<a href="../index.html">


<img src="images/boyP.jpg" 
onclick="var node=parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode; if( node.click ) { return node.click(); } else { return true; }">
                            
</a>
</div><!--end bild2 -->

Answer (score 0):

Here's is the solution with `background-image` instead of `<img>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/XhtTJ/1/

And here's the solution with `<img>` positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/myRKK/1/

Just bear in mind that in both cases you need to set a `height` for your `div`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and for taking your time :)! But the thing i was trying to do was not having do specify a width. All the pictures are the same height but not the same width. i got it working if i added float left but i want the picture centered. any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand you... You define a width: `<div class="bild2" style="width:406px;">`. How can you say: "thing i was trying to do was not having do specify a width"?

Comment: Because i have to. I want to avoid that. That is my question.

Comment: This means that you want all images to be cropped at a fixed width and height, right?

Comment: no all images have the same height but different widths, i want to avoid having to put in a specific width on every html file. Maybe i am misunderstanding you?

Comment: Totally! I can't understand what you're looking for... Do you need to show you pictures in the same height but cropped widths?

Comment: I have a site where i want to put up my pictures for display. I am a photographer. And they look different so i am trying to either save them with the same width or height depending on what kind of pic i am using. When i had pics with the same width it worked fine, but now i want to put up portraits and i saved them with the same height. I have a lot of pics i want to put up on my site, but i don't want it to be a hazard.

Comment: So thats why i want the border to wrap around the picture automatically without me having to specify anything, except either the specific height or width that i already cropped the pic in  :). Do you understand me now?

Comment: My answer above cover your needs perfectly. You have a container (`<div>`) with a specified width and height. You call your images in this container and since I defined `overflow:hidden` and the center position of the image, the container masks your images. The position of the image in both examples is either defined as `background:url('yourimage.jpg') no-repeat center center` or as `position:absolute;left:-50%;top:-50%`.